# Trying to update a column

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to update the entire column, but it seems to only update the first matching row.

This is my code

```
 $sql = 'UPDATE tree SET sort_order = sort_order+1 WHERE sort_order > :sort_order AND reply_to = :id';
        $query = $app->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':sort_order' => get_sort(),
                              ':id' =>$id
                              ));
```

How do i update the column? I know there are more matches their.

Comment: Your query looks correct for your stated intention.  Sample data and actual/desired results might help explain what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

> but it seems to only update the first matching row

Yeah, cause you have used a filter using `WHERE` clause as seen below

```
WHERE sort_order > :sort_order AND reply_to = :id'
```

if you want to update all rows then remove the `WHERE` condition

```
UPDATE tree SET sort_order = sort_order+1;
```

Comment: Yes. say that i want to update records above 5. The where clause is not the problem.

Comment: Then remove the `AND reply_to = :id'` condition from query.

Comment: what if i want to update all records above 5, with value 1 in row reply_to? How would i solve that?